# Select All rows in Jquery Datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a datatables in which I can select multiple row onclick but how can I select all the row on a click of button and at the same time all rows are highlighted with selection (Can you please give example of selection for current page and all the pages). I have written a code to get multiple selected value.

Checkbox will also do but then how to get selected value.

**Below is code for single and multiple selection.**

```
 var oTable = $("#example").dataTable();

    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
                        $(this).toggleClass('selected');

    });
```

**Code to get selected value on button submit.**

```
var row = oTable.rows('.selected').data();

var jsonArr = "[";

        if(row != null && row.length){

            for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
                var row1 = row[i]; // this will give me one row details
                        // row1[0] will give me column details
                        jsonArr = jsonArr + "{\"ID\":" + row1[0] + "},";

                }   
             jsonArr = jsonArr + "]";
```

Comment: Hi,I really want to know want went wrong that I got negative votes."Can you please give example of selection for current page and all the pages" is this because of this but I googled I am not getting click like select all so I asked for some example. All I am getting is input checkbox select all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What will probably help you is [TableTools extension](http://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/). There is an [example](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/TableTools/examples/select_multi.html) with select_all and select_none buttons, and those work for all pages.

One default limitation is that select_all will ignore current filtering, but that is easy to solve using the code below. Providing "true" argument to fnSelectAll enables the filter-aware selection.

```
tableTools: {
    sRowSelect: 'multi',
    aButtons: [
        {
            sExtends: 'select_all',
            sButtonText: 'Select All',
            fnClick: function (nButton, oConfig, oFlash) {
                TableTools.fnGetInstance('example').fnSelectAll(true);
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I have some how solved my purpose manually. But I will definitely try your solution and post again for the time I am posting my code

Comment: I tried the below approach as well, but it quickly proved to be not scalable. The problem with it is when you do $('.case') you only select checkboxes that have been created by datatables, which is usually only page 1. If you just click through all the pages, and then press the header checkbox, only then it will actually select everything on all pages.

Comment: @pise, in addition to what I mentioned above, I gave up creating a manual solution for this. It turned out much easier just to use TableTools. But if the amount of data is relatively small, javascript processing of checkboxes can work as well.

Comment: the tableTools are deprecated apparently. Both the Buttons and the Select extensions are needed now.\

Answer (score 0):

According to the [doc](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/TableTools/examples/select_multi.html) there is a inbuilt function for this. No need extra coding,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        tableTools: {
            "sRowSelect": "multi",
            "aButtons": [ "select_all", "select_none" ]
        }
    } );
} );
```

You will need the JS file defined at the doc and aprt from that they have missed to included the following related CSS file

- http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/TableTools/css/dataTables.tableTools.css

This is  all it takes.

Answer (score -1):

Thank You for your help. But some how I did my select all manually the only loop hole in this is, if I select header check box all the row check box will be selected but when we go on next page eg: page no 2 header check box will be checked and again to select all page no 2 rows check box I have to uncheck and check header checkbox.

What I did:

I have added input type checbox thead tr and tbody tr and gave class ='case' to all child input. On click of select all calling a function to select/deselect child rows

```
<thead>
     <tr>
       <th><input type='checkbox' id='selectall'/></th>
       <th>Patient Name</th>
     </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
 <tr>
    <td class style='text-align: center;'><input type='checkbox' class='case' name='case'id = '"item.uid+"_I' /></td>
    <td>"+item.name+"</td>
  <tr>
</tbody>


// function to select/deselect all input checkbox

to check uncheck all input box
$('#selectall').click(function(event) {  //on click

    if(this.checked) { // check select status
          $('.case').each(function() { //loop through each checkbox
          this.checked = true;  //select all checkboxes with class "checkbox"   
          $(this).closest("tr").addClass("selected");              
     });
     }else{
           $('.case').each(function() { //loop through each checkbox
           this.checked = false; //deselect all checkboxes with class "checkbox"
           $(this).closest("tr").removeClass("selected");
     });        
    }
});


// select/deselect function if single row is selected
$('#patientdata tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    var rowID = this.id;
    if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
      $(this).removeClass('selected');
        $('#'+rowID+"_I").attr('checked', false);
        }
        else {
              $(this).addClass('selected');
               $('#'+rowID+"_I").attr('checked', true);
            }
        });
```

Thanks

Comment: it will keep selecting in next pages?